# 502 Active FTP not allowed in Netbean while synchornizing to remote Server

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to synchronize my local project in remote server. It created the base directory also, but can't upload files. The Error message is 502 Active FTP not allowed. I am using netbean IDE. What should be the problem??

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a 502 Active FTP Not Allowed is a message coming from your FTP server. I believe it is telling you that it only allows FTP connections in passive mode.

In *Manage Remote Connections* for the connection you are using, check the box *Passive Mode* and try again.